# Sorting 2d array row and column wize

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static boolean  absoluteSorted(int[][] mat) {

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
            if(mat[i][j]<mat[mat.length-1][mat[i].length-1]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

what is wrong with my code??

Example:
Input:           Output:false            Input: -5 0 5   Output:true
2   0   0                                      -2 9 12
8   6   0                                       9 10 20
4   5   8

Comment: What do you want the code to do?

Comment: I want to sort the array columns and rows and if they’re sorted return true

Comment: The question "What do you want the code to do?" is asking you to supply example input and output.

Comment: Give us an exemple of an unordered array as input and the output you espect. Otherwise you will not be answered.

Answer (score 0):

> what is wrong with my code?

If you want to check that the columns and rows are sorted, you need to compare **all** element with the next one in its column and the next one in its row.

Your code is comparing against the last element in each row and column.

Also, your code returns `true` on the first element that is "in order".  It should only return when it has checked all elements that need checking.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this line:

```
if(mat[i][j]<mat[mat.length-1][mat[i].length-1]) {
```

Should be something like:

```
if(mat[i][j] < mat[i-1][j-1]) { // Except when i or j == 0
```

Because "sorting" means comparing each cell in turn.